# Función PL/SQL con INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy intentando hacer unos ejercicios, pero me he bloqueado, os dejo el enunciado:

Actividad 1

• Realizar una función llamada SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS que calcule la suma de los complementos de un
empleado le pasaremos como entrada un DNI y nos devolverá la suma de los complementos de ese
empleado.

```
N_EMPLEADOS_COMPL
===================
DNI       COD_COMPL
--------- ---------
1         C1
1         C2
1         C3
3         C3
3         C4
4         C1
5         C3
5         C5


N_COMPLEMENTOS
=====================
COD_COMPL EUROS_COMPL
--------- -----------
C1         100
C2         120
C3         140
C4         160
C5         180
```

El código que llevo es el siguiente:

```
create or replace FUNCTION SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS(P_DNI N_EMPLEADOS.DNI%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
    SUM_COMP NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(COM.EUROS_COMPL) INTO SUM_COMP
        FROM N_COMPLEMENTOS COM INNER JOIN N_EMPLEADOS_COMPL EMP_COM
        ON COM.COD_COMPL = EMP_COM.COD_COMPL
        GROUP BY EMP_COM.DNI
        HAVING EMP_COM.DNI = P_DNI;

        RETURN SUM_COMP;

END;
```

Comment: `P_DNI` y `N_EMPLEADOS` son dos argumentos distintos, ¿verdad? Si es así los argumentos debes separarlos por la coma `,`, y además a `P_DNI` debes definirle un tipo, ya sea `VARCHAR2` o el tipo que tenga en la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rehíce la base de datos y volví a insertar los datos que facilitas como ejemplo, y durante el proceso me di cuenta que en la declaración de el `IN` de la función, el tipo de `P_DNI` es incorrecto, ya que la tabla las has nombrado mal poniendo `N_EMPLEADOS.DNI%TYPE` en vez de `N_EMPLEADOS_COMPL.DNI%TYPE`. Cambia eso y vuelve a ejecutar la función, la he probado y funciona.